# how to turn off android service or turn off Reciever?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

How can I turn off `Service` in Android? OR How can I unregiser or turn off `Reciever`?

    `public void onDestroy()` doesn't work

This is my `Service`

```
public class LockScreenService extends Service{
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
public static volatile boolean isMustBeLocked;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock k1;

    //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    if(isMustBeLocked) {
        KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        k1 = km.newKeyguardLock("IN");
        k1.disableKeyguard();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

        mReceiver = new LockScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        super.onCreate();

    }
    else{
        Log.e("LockScreenService","TEST");
    }

}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
/*@Override
public void onPause(){

}*/
public void destroy(){
    if(mReceiver!=null) {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        Log.e("","TEST destroy3");
    }
    Log.e("","TEST destroy2");
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(mReceiver!=null) {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        Log.e("","TEST destroy");
    }Log.e("","TEST destroying");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean 'onDestroy()` doesn't work? What doesn't work? How do you know?

Answer (score 1):

To turn off the service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class)
stopService(intent);
```

To unregister Receiver be sure to first :

```
unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
```

Answer (score 0):

Service-  you call stopService.  Inside the service you can call stopSelf.  Receivers you call unregisterReceiver  (only works for dynamically created receivers, not with ones registered in the manifest).